# Ian Fritz - Chaos - Cubic non linearity

Tags: diodes, non-linear

I was reading Ian Fritz overview on [chaotic circuits](https://ijfritz.byethost4.com/Chaos/ch_close.htm).

As an example of non-linear circuit, he presents the following schematics
[image: Cubic non-linearity]

This circuit is said to output a signal of the form x.(1-x^2) where x is the input signal.

As I understand the circuit, the face-to-face diodes are supposed to introduce a cubic non-linearity x^3.

Could someone explain how two face-to-face diodes can output a cubic non-linearity ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use a simulator and see what result you get. If it works, you'll see that the important thing is that they are zener diodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: it says "*of the form*", not "strictly", which means it's an antisymmetric waveform (odd function) due to the \$x^3\$ part. And if you look at the circuit closely, the two Zener diodes with the 2.2 kΩ form a so-called *dead-zone*, because the input voltage will need to be greater, or lesser than \$\approx\pm V_Z\pm 0.7\$. This makes the voltage at the noninverting input be (vortually) flat over a certain range, while at the other input the voltage is normal. Their difference will be S-shaped, or that of an odd function.

As suggested by [Andy aka](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/566717/ian-fritz-chaos-cubic-non-linearity#comment1481752_566717), grab your favourite SPICE simulator and convince yourself:

[image: test]

The purpose is to generate a voltage that has two slopes, positive and negative, with inflexion points, based on a linear input. This is one key step in creating chaotic circuits. See [Chua's circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chua%27s_circuit), or [Lorenz attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) (or [other](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/534036/95619) [answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/531996/95619)) for some more explanations. It's not mandatory to be Zener diodes as long as the circuit can behave like a dead-zone (but a Zener does simplify things).

Comment: Ok thanks ! I actually tried to use a spice simulator (within Eagle), but I got a linear response .... I'm quite new to spice, so I guess I must have missed something. But the "dead zone" explanation is what I was looking for here, so thank you very much.